# Adding choices to NewItemForm

Tags: 2010, list, development, custom-form, field-controls

I've got an application that contains a custom list. I'm using the default NewItemForms to create new Items. One filed of the form is a select/combobox. now I want to set the choices of the select dynamicly.
That means I want to set the choices each time the form pops up.

One idea was perhabs to get access from a "code-behind-class"?

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom field type would meet this need. You can customize the rendering of the field on the new/edit/display forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx

If you want to go the code-behind route, then you would be creating an entirely new form, and you would be responsible for any future updates. (When users add a column to the list, that column would not be on your form.)